# JavaScript Class Definition Starts with (function()

Tags: javascript

Check source code of ApiValidator.js at [github](https://github.com/Peer5/ShareFest/blob/master/core/apiValidators/ApiValidator.js). I was taught to define a JS class using `var apple = new function() {...` But this one starts with `(function(){....`? Why is this?

Comment: Neither `new function() { ...` nor `(function() { ...` are ways to define a class in JavaScript.

Comment: Unless you are using ecmascript 6 there is no such thing as a class in javascript. What you are defining is functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the GitHub starts with and ends with:

```
(function () {
  //...
})();
```

This is called as a self-executing function or ["Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). This encloses an anonymous function inside it and immediately executes it. And one more thing:

```
var apple = new function() {
}
```

The above is not a valid way of defining an object or a class.

Comment: well `new function() { ... }` definitely will create an *object*, but I don't think too many people would say it creates a "class".

Comment: That is NOT a closure. It's a self-executing function. A closure is only defined when something is being held on to that would have otherwise been garbage collected but can't because of a reference inside of some other function (a closure).

Comment: @Pointy Oops... Sorry about my mistake. How do I correct it? Should I remove it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar maybe just edit the answer?

Comment: Technically it is called an "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: @Pointy Grr... What should the [edit] contain! `:P`

Comment: I wouldn't bother editing it. This question has been asked many times before and will almost certainly be closed.

Comment: Done it. Have a look.

Comment: @PraveenKumar well I guess you could say that it's a (somewhat unusual) way of instantiating an object. I guess it might be a useful way of building an object with a single expression when you can't use an object initializer for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `var apple = new function() {}` is not a way of define a class.

and `(function () {...})()` is a self-executing function that calling itself immediately.

For example: `var fn = function () { // code };`

so `fn()` and `(function() { // code })()` is similar.